# How do German speakers idiomatically express the idea of "Ce n’est pas donné à tout le monde de ..." in French?

Tags: expression, french

> Tu as vraiment de la chance, XXX, **c’est pas donné à tout le monde d**’être amie avec un joueur de tennis mondialement connu.

We were having a conversation in French, and I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in German. This French expression literally means "***It's not given to everyone to*** (be friends with a world-renowned tennis player)", or more naturally, "***Not many people/folks get to*** (be friends with a world-renowned tennis player)".

The following sprang to mind as its German equivalent, but I wonder if this phrasing might not come across as a bit too straightforward, mundane? How is this idea commonly expressed in German?

> **Nicht viele Leute** sind mit einem weltberühmten Tennisspieler befreundet.

Comment: Is there some irony (or plain fandom) in that expression, or am I just guessing from the literal translation?

Answer (score 8):

A very literal translation would be:

> Es ist nicht jedem gegeben...

But that’s typically used for personal traits and talents or rather, lack thereof. It’s also a touch stilted and old-fashioned.

In your example, the simpler

> Nicht jeder kann...

is probably the better choice, being more colloquial and idiomatic.

Your translations would also work well.

Comment: A less stilted alternative (in many cases) for the first sentence would be "Nicht jeder hat das Zeug zu ...".

Comment: In colloquial speech this would probably be inverted: "[Es] kann ja nicht jeder mit einem...."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "Nicht jeder hat das Zeug dazu, mit einem Weltklasse Tennisspieler befreundet zu sein"? That only works for being or achieving something special. "Nicht jeder hat das Zeug zum Soldaten/ Tennisspieler/ ..." or "Nicht jeder hat das Zeug dazu, den Mount Everest zu besteigen/ einer Wildkatze in die Augen zu sehen/ ...

Comment: @hajef: Yes, as I wrote, it's an alternative for the first sentence. The one that came with the restriction that it's "typically used for personal traits and talents or rather, lack thereof".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It has an entirely different scope. "Nicht jeder hat das Zeug dazu, freundlich und entgegenkommend zu sein" might work but only if you emphasize that it is hard to be friendly/ act like it. "Es ist nicht jedem gegeben, freundlich und entgegenkommend zu sein" works fine and simply emphasizes that these are qualities that not everyone has.

Comment: @hajef: That's why I wrote "in many cases".

Comment: Der Einschränkung zum ersten Beispiel, auf Talent und Eigenschaften schließe ich mich nicht an.

Comment: The "Nicht jeder kann" form would work here in the sense of "Nicht jeder kann von sich behaupten mit einem weltberühmten Tennisspieler befreundet zu sein"

Comment: The first expression would have a sarcastic undertone, unless the speaker is of the fan-type who honestly admires celebrity. In which case it would also sound rather stilted indeed.